# How to prove non-monotonic sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am asked to prove a sequence is not monotone, the sequence is increasing, but not every term is greater than the preceding so I know by definition the sequence is not monotone. I was wondering what technique I can use to prove a sequence is not monotone because simply showing that the terms are not increasing monotonously is not going to cut it as a proof. Also my sequence is in Z+ and all the values I get are positive, (just not increasing monotonously).
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: FInding a single counterexample to monotonicity is sufficient.

Comment: Why would "showing that the terms are not increasing monotonously" not work? All you have to do is find some positive integers $n,m$ such that $n<m$ and $x_n>x_m$.

Comment: show us your sequence that would it make simpler to talk about it

Comment: @JohnGriffin that is wrong.  think  it could be monotone increasing or decreasing

Comment: The sequence is (x+((-1)^x)2). This is what I have using the above answers. Since the sequence is increasing we would assume if it were monotonic we would find all Sn < Sm whenever n < m. But since we can find an m < n when Sn < Sm we know the sequence is not monotonic. In particular we choose n=2 and m=3, then Sn=4, Sm=1 thus 2 < 3 (Sn < Sm) but 1 < 4  (m < n). I'm sure my teacher will say this is not a formal proof.

Comment: @miracle173 Well that negates the case that it is not increasing. The case that it is not decreasing follows similarly.

Comment: What I have above my teacher would call scratch work then he would normally write a formal proof using the above information but I can't think of any similar questions that he has covered. Does anyone have any advice as to how I should start my proof, for example if it were only (-1)^n I could let let n be odd or even then find a contradiction. But since all the values in my sequence are positive I'm not sure how to set up the formal proof. Please don't do the proof for me, just the kind advice that you would expect from a teacher for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s_n$ is monotonically increasing means

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:\; s_n<s_{n+1}.\tag  1$$
Check if the sequence 
$$ s_n=n+2(-1)^n$$
is monotonically increasing.

**Proof:**

We have

$$s_2=4>1=s_3.$$
Therefore the sequence is not monotonically increasing, because this contracdicts $(1)$ for $n=2$.

$\blacksquare$

That is the proof. What are you missing?

---

A more formal way:

We have
$$4>1\\
\implies s_2>s_3 \\
 \implies \lnot (s_2<s_3) \\
\implies\exists n \in \mathbb{N}:\lnot (\;s_n<s_{n+1})\\
\iff \lnot \forall n \in \mathbb{N}:\;s_n <s_{n-+1}$$

which is the negation of $(1)$